# Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i want to  make a `cell` variable and  assign `dequeueReusableCell` for avoid duplication code. I have no idea how can I do that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : UITableViewCell!
        if let url = media.url {
            if Helper.isImageType(url: url)
            {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsFeedImageTableViewViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedImageTableViewViewCell
                cell.imageTappedDelegate = self
            }else
            {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsFeedVideoTableViewViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedVideoTableViewViewCell
                cell.videoTappedDelegate = self
            }
            cell.linkTappedDelegate  = self
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xF2F2F2)
            cell.isAccessibilityElement = true
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            tableViewIndex = indexPath
            if let  _states = states?[indexPath.section]{
                cell.state = _states[indexPath.row]
            }
            return cell
        }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

If you see my code it only difference

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsFeedVideoTableViewViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedImageTableViewViewCell
```

And

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsFeedVideoTableViewViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedVideoTableViewViewCell
```

Other lines of code are the same.

I am trying to declare variable this but it is not working:

```
let cell: UITableViewCell!
```

> Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'imageTappedDelegate'

UPDATE:- added cell class definitions:

```
class NewsFeedTableViewViewCell : BaseTableViewCell{  
    var statisticsSlidingCellId = "statisticsSlidingCellId"
    var linkTappedDelegate : LinkTappedDelegate!
    var state : State?{
        didSet{
          }
    }
}

class   NewsFeedImageTableViewViewCell: NewsFeedTableViewViewCell{
    var imageTappedDelegate : ImageTappedDelegate!
}

class   NewsFeedVideoTableViewViewCell : NewsFeedTableViewViewCell{
    var videoTappedDelegate : VideoTappedDelegate!
}
```

Comment: How do you declare your two Cell classes? -- `NewsFeedImageTableViewViewCell` and `NewsFeedVideoTableViewViewCell`. Before reducing some code in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, have you reduced duplicate code in the two classes?

Comment: `NewsFeedImageTableViewViewCell` and `NewsFeedVideoTableViewViewCell` inherited  `NewsFeedTableViewViewCell` .

Comment: Why don't you declare your `cell` as `NewsFeedTableViewViewCell`, if it has all common properties in it?

Comment: @OOPer no!   `cell.imageTappedDelegate = self` and 
           `cell.videoTappedDelegate = self` not same and some for property are difference

Comment: you need to cast your cell to whatever type has those properties before trying to assign them. If all the properties are in one subclass, then initialize the table cell as that subclass instead of the base UITableViewCell

Comment: Show your class definitions! Do you think we can find what are common and what are uncommon without seeing your code???

Comment: @OOPer would you check my   update question

Comment: I repeat, show your Cell class definitions.

Comment: @OOPer added cell class definitions

Comment: Oh, thanks. It's the easiest way to tell others what you have.

Comment: @OOPer would you help me please how can i solve this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150538/discussion-between-cristan-lika-and-ooper).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve your issue, cast to the correct type before assigning the delegate. Whenever you reference cell, its of type UITableViewCell so those properties/methods on your custom subclasses do not exist.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : NewsFeedTableViewViewCell!
        if let url = media.url {
            if Helper.isImageType(url: url)
            {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsFeedImageTableViewViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedImageTableViewViewCell
                (cell as ! NewsFeedImageTableViewCell).imageTappedDelegate = self
            }else
            {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsFeedVideoTableViewViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedVideoTableViewViewCell
                (cell as! NewsFeedVideoTableViewCell).videoTappedDelegate = self
            }
            cell.linkTappedDelegate  = self
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xF2F2F2)
            cell.isAccessibilityElement = true
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            tableViewIndex = indexPath
            if let  _states = states?[indexPath.section]{
                cell.state = _states[indexPath.row]
            }
            return cell
        }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very near to the Josh Hamet's, so, I added some comments.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let url = media.url {
        let cell: NewsFeedTableViewViewCell //<- common class
        if Helper.isImageType(url: url) {
            let imageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsFeedImageTableViewViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedImageTableViewViewCell
            //When accessing `imageTappedDelegate`, the type of the cell needs to be `NewsFeedImageTableViewViewCell`.
            imageCell.imageTappedDelegate = self
            cell = imageCell
        } else {
            let videoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsFeedVideoTableViewViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedVideoTableViewViewCell
            //When accessing `videoTappedDelegate`, the type of the cell needs to be `NewsFeedVideoTableViewViewCell`.
            videoCell.videoTappedDelegate = self
            cell = videoCell
        }
        //When accessing common properties, the type of the cell can be `NewsFeedTableViewViewCell`.
        cell.linkTappedDelegate  = self
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xF2F2F2)
        cell.isAccessibilityElement = true
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        tableViewIndex = indexPath
        if let  _states = states?[indexPath.section]{
            cell.state = _states[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: @cristanlika, I have tested my code in my Xcode. Some parts filled by my guess may cause an error, but never that line. Please check if you really entered my whole code correctly.